# Creating tiles in Mapnik

Tags: mapnik

I have installed Mapnik and successfully tested it. Now I am facing the problem of creating my own customized tiles. I have googled it but everywhere it was telling about OSM tile generation.

*My vision is simple:* I have a huge map data of my target area. I want to create my own custom map in Mapnik/Tilemill. Then create tiles and upload them into server. A step by step instruction would be helpful to me since I am a newbie in Mapnik.

*The main problem:* How can I create tiles with my own data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like some suggested... I think your path from now should be:

1. Put data in some format supported by TileMill (if you want simplest, go with shapefiles, otherwise PostGIS database)
2. In Tilemill, load your data and define the symbolisation for your map, then export a Mapnik XML config file. You can use this XML file together with `generate_tiles.py` script to create your tiles with Mapnik in the bounding box and zoom levels you specify (to specify bbox, zoomlevels, modify `generate_tiles.py`, last few lines I think).
3. You can then use these generated tiles in a web app via OpenLayers or Leaflet.

This is just a rough outline that should get you started, you can ask more specific questions and I'll clarify.

1. Structure your data
2. TileMill (GUI + preview of your map)
3. Mapnik XML export
4. Mapnik tile generation (actual rendering)
5. Upload tiles to your server (no need to use mbtiles)
6. Serve tiles via XYZ or TMS layer in Openlayers

Answer (score 3):

There are many good step-by-step tutorials for mapnik on its web site.

If you are a Python programmer, then the [Python tutorial](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/GettingStartedInPython) will probably make the most sense. There are [other tutorials](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/MapnikTutorials) though, all worth a look.

If you are really trying to use TileMill, then you can't go past the [crash course tutorial](https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/introduction/).

Comment: I wrote that I have tested successfully. That means I have done the tutorials. I need to create tiles and upload to server. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to use mapnik and tilemill as the server (which is how it is normally done). I guess you want to pre-generate every tile and then upload them to a server? If so, use TileCache or TileStache, preseeed whatever you want, and you are done.

Comment: Dont be sorry Man!!! You are trying to help me. I have installed mapnik. I can create .mbtiles through tilemill. Now my challenge is to create a server from where I can preview that basemap and create some services through PostGIS database such as routing, geocoding etc. Thanks

Comment: Here are few projects that support tilemill / mbtiles, check out: https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/wiki/Implementations

Comment: Tutorial link is 404

Comment: Updated (you could have done that yourself too - just click on Edit below the question).